# PHP - matching and replacing urls

Tags: php, url

If I have multiple urls like this in a variable that a user enters called `$url`:

```
http://www.example.com/home
/home
?home=true
home/
```

And it's all supposed to be under the `www.example.com` website,

How can I replace the urls to their right form?

Something like this :

```
http://www.example.com/home => http://www.example.com/home
/ihome                      => http://www.example.com/ihome
?home=true                  => http://www.example.com/ihome?home=true 
home/                       => http://www.example.com/ihome/home/
```

Both last with current page to `/ihome`.

Comment: Tell us how this is used. Submit some code. What you're saying now can be done by parsing strings, but I'm guessing that's not what you want to do.

Comment: are you trying to concatenate these into 1? Not sure I understand

Comment: Are those in a string, array, object(which could basically be an array...), etc???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your question is about [relative URLs](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html).

Suppose you are at location http://example.com/home, and have a link to about page, which is hardlinked to http://example.com/about. This is accessible within 'home.php' (or wherever /home is hosted) by relatively linking `<a href="about">About</a>`. This follows standard directory protocols and won't change much. Plenty of these examples are documented in the link I provided for more information.

**Edit:** Initial question was too vague for my answer to be true to what the question really calls for. Proper answer, how to replace, is below.

Use `str_replace()`, as indicated in the comment below. An example, for how to convert "/ihome". Suppose we are at location http://example.com/about.

```
$body = ...; // assuming this is going through whole php document

$url = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
$tokens = explode('/', $url);   
array_pop($tokens); // remove "/about"
$url = implode("", $tokens);
str_replace("/ihome", $url . "/ihome", $body);
```

The last line is certainly up for debate, but this should work. If you have multiple links you want to check, you may want to go with a regex approach (ie any links defined as just "/sub" or any queries "?query").

Answer (score 0):

Theres probably a way to do this with a single preg_replace function in each loop, but something like this should do the trick.

```
<?php

foreach($urls as $key => $val)
    if(!preg_match('/^http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\//', $val))
        $url[$key] = 'http://www.example.com/'.ltrim($val, '/');
```